# The first char of my array doesnt get printed out

Tags: c, arrays

I want to program a Hangman game, but before comparing strings etc. I just wanted to scroll through the array automatically to see if that works - it doesn't, well, not as I imagined.

Everything besides the very first character gets printed out, but why?

```
int gameWon = 0;
char secretWord[7][1] = {{"H"},{"A"},{"N"},{"G"},{"M"},{"A"},{"N"}};
char guessedChar;

while(gameWon != 1)
{
    printf("Guess a single letter: ");
    scanf("%s", &guessedChar);

    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
            printf("%c\n", secretWord[i][0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong format specifier to `scanf`:

```
scanf("%s", &guessedChar);
```

The `%s` format specifier expects a `char *` which points to the first element of a `char` array and places a null terminated string at that location.  What you passed in was the address of a single `char`.  This caused `scanf` to write past the memory location of `guessedChar`, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  In this case, it manifested as a nearby variable getting overwritted, specifically the first element of the array `secretWord`.

Change this to use `%c` instead, which is for reading single characters.  Also, be sure to put a space before it in the format string to absorb any whitespace characters left in the input buffer:

```
scanf(" %c", &guessedChar);
```

Comment: The stack growing down may be subtlety that is missed on how writing one beyond `guessedChar` would overwrite the first character in `secretWord`.

Answer (score 1):

The type that you specify in `scanf` is wrong, you pass in an address to a character but the format specifier `%s` expects a string which will cause undefined behavior. My guess is that it affects the rest of your code.

Also the type of `secretword` seems a bit odd, why not just an array or string?

```
char secretWord[] = "HANGMAN";
```

`scanf` is not a good choice of reading from the keyboard, instead use `fgets()` and strip off the ending \n or like in your case, just read the first char. Then you don't need to deal with the fact that scanf leaves characters in the keyboard buffer.

```
while (... )
{
    printf("Guess a single letter: ");
    char buffer[128];
    if (fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin) != NULL)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < strlen(secretWord); ++i)
      {
        if (buffer[0] == secretWord[i])
        {
        ...
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did it this way to let the program run through the array and search for a certain character. for example if "M" is guessed, I want to get the location in the 2D Array where the M is (or is not).

Comment: i don't see why you need a 2d array, just check in a normal array.

Comment: Sure seems like `char secretWord[] = "HANGMAN";` would make things a lot easier. And if you never change `secretWord`, then `const char *secretWord = "HANGMAN";` would suffice. Either way, you could simply `printf ("%s\n", secretWord);`